# linker command failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios

I got an error:

```
Framework not found FacebookSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation)
```

When I copy my project to another macbook to run,I found this error.I used the facebooksdk framework.If I deleted the facebook framework in my project and then add the facebook framework again to my project can solved this error.But I don't want to solve this problem like that.Any other better idea.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You should check **Framework Search Path** in target **Build Settings**, best way is write framework directory path with macro like `$(SOURCE_ROOT)` is allow linker find framework on different macs.

For example: 
if my project live in this folder

```
/Users/sage/Documents/devs/project1/
```

`$(SOURCE_ROOT)` will be `/Users/sage/Documents/devs/project1` 
in Framework Searh Path I should write `$(SOURCE_ROOT)/libs`

Comment: But I got many warning about 50.The warning is "missing file",like fbsession.h file.What should I do?

Comment: can you show import string? in build settings also **Header Search Path** parameters where you can write path to headers, but this header should be in framework so problem can be in import

Comment: I import like that "#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>" and my Header Search Path like that "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include".